# c# WPF - How to recognize mouse click outside control without blocking other controls from being clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, mousecapture

I now read many threads and tried and so on. I don't get it.

**Question**
When using MouseCapture any other control isn't motioned. Cannot click something. No Highlightings happens on mouse over. MouseCaption is blocking that. Clicking Twice is necessary. How to avoid that?

**Basically**
I created a custom autocompletebox which consists of a textbox for free input and a dropdown as textblock containing suggested result-element by the given input. This is pretty like a standard ComboBox.

From Combobox we know, when it is expanded and one clicks somewhere else the dropdown is collapsed.

I want exactly the same behavior like the combobox uses.

Because I am not the first one asking that, I tried several things but didn't get them fully working.

**What I still tried and I failed with.**

1. Adding `OnLostFocus` event to the textbox does not recognize any mouse clicks to non-focusable Elements.
2. Using `Mous.Caption(this)` with `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` to receive any mouse clicks on any place on the window.

   - Yeah that works! I can collapse my dropdown, Un-Capture the mouse again.
   - But: The mouse caption prevents me from clicking to other UIElement. Checkboxes and RadioBoxes wont be toggled. Just hovering the mouse over a Checkbox or anything else is not highlighting that element any more. Instead I now need to click twice to check a textbox.
   - I can't figure out, how to solve that.
3. Also what did not work was that when the mouse-capture event was fired, I cannot figure out where the click has been made.

   - `source` as well as `e.OriginalSource` are equal to my custom control
   - Getting the Mouse-Position may be an option. But did not find to get the position of my control related to the mouse-position. any properties on the control return NaN.
4. At first I was not able to recognize any difference between `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` and `MouseLeftButtonDown`.

   - I thought the first one, when directly releasing mouse-capture, would fire the mouseclick event to its original destination without the mouse capture any more. It doesn't.
   - I got it by using the Hittest. Is it that way to do so?

**Some Code**

XAML of AutoCompleteBox

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.Wpf.Application.Control.AutoCompleteBoxControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="AutoCompleteBox"
             PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="AutoComplete_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBox Name="AutoCompleteTextBox" Text="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=TextBoxText, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=TextBoxHeight}" Width="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=TextBoxWidth}" Padding="5, 3, 5, 3" KeyUp="AutoCompleteTextBoxControl_KeyUp" LostKeyboardFocus="AutoCompleteTextBox_OnLostKeyboardFocus"/>
            <Popup Name="ResultStackPopup" IsOpen="True" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteTextBox}" Placement="Custom">
                <Border Name="ResultStackBorder" Width="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=SuggestionListWidth}" Height="{Binding ElementName=AutoCompleteBox, Path=SuggestionListHeight}" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="White" Margin="1,0,1,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                        <StackPanel Name="ResultStack"></StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </Popup>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

relevant code behind:

```
//Whenever the dropdown is expanded, the mouse caption is started:
this.CaptureMouse();
```

mouse-down event:

```
private void AutoComplete_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            if (!this.IsMouseInBounds())
            {
                //Release MouseCaption
                this.ReleaseMouseCapture();

                //Collapse SuggestionList
                var border = (this.ResultStack.Parent as ScrollViewer)?.Parent as Border;
                if (border != null)
                {
                    border.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }
        }
    }

private bool IsMouseInBounds()
{
    Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

    // Perform the hit test against a given portion of the visual object tree.
    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, point);

    if (result != null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

### Edit

Unfortunately the Popup is (afaik) not a member of the visualTree. So the hittest for the Popup does not work. So I tried to get the position of the Popup to check with the Mouse-position.

The TransformToAncestor method is to be used as everyone is saying that.
But this does not seem to work properly:

The following three calls do return exactly the same points:

```
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
    Point relativePointThis = this.TransformToAncestor(parentWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    Point relativePointPopup = this.ResultStackPopup.TransformToAncestor(parentWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
    Point relativePointBorder = this.ResultStackBorder.TransformToAncestor(parentWindow).Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not give up and made some steps forward.

**Answers to:**

**1)**
Either make the Window Focusable or even don't do it that way.

**2)**
Using the right CaptureMode by `Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);` at least solves that the DropDown keeps being interactive with mouse-over etc. (ofcourse, because it's a child of the capturing-control).

The rest of the Window keeps beeing blocked by mouse-capture. One may just realizes, that this is also normal behavior for a standard ComboBox. So one could live with that.

**3)**
Getting the inbound-click-check via the mouse position can be handled with the following code. Notice that the mouse-position is given relative to the given element. In this case the AutoCompleteBox is given itself via `this`. So the upper left corner will be `{0.0, 0.0}`.

```
private bool IsMouseInBounds()
{
    //Get MousePosition relative to the AutoCompleteBox
    Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(this);

    //Actual Width and Heigth of AutoCompleteBox
    var widthAuto = this.ActualWidth;
    var heightAuto = this.ActualHeight;
    var upLeftXAuto = 0.0;
    var upLeftYAuto = 0.0;
    var downRightXAuto = upLeftXAuto + widthAuto;
    var downRightYAuto = upLeftYAuto + heightAuto;

    //Actual Width and Height of DropDown
    var widthDropDown = this.ResultStackBorder.ActualWidth;
    var heightDropDown = this.ResultStackBorder.ActualHeight;
    double upLeftXDropDown;
    double upLeftYDropDown;

    //Actual Position of DropDown (may be aligned right or center)
    CalculateAlignmentForPopUp(out upLeftXDropDown, out upLeftYDropDown, 0.0, 0.0, widthAuto, heightAuto, widthDropDown);

    var downRightXDropDown = upLeftXDropDown + widthDropDown;
    var downRightYDropDown = upLeftYDropDown + heightDropDown;

    //Calc IsInbound
    return (
             point.X >= upLeftXAuto && point.X <= downRightXAuto &&
             point.Y >= upLeftYAuto && point.Y <= downRightYAuto
         ) || (
             point.X >= upLeftXDropDown && point.X <= downRightXDropDown &&
             point.Y >= upLeftYDropDown && point.Y <= downRightYDropDown
         );
}



private void CalculateAlignmentForPopUp(out double newX, out double newY, double xAuto, double yAuto, double widthAuto, double heightAuto, double widthPopup)
{
    newX = 0.0;
    newY = 0.0;

    switch (this.ListHorizontalAlignment)
    {
        case "Right":
            newX = xAuto + widthAuto - widthPopup;
            newY = yAuto + heightAuto;
            break;
        case "Center":
            newX = xAuto + widthAuto / 2 - widthPopup / 2;
            newY = yAuto + heightAuto;
            break;
        default:
            newY = yAuto + heightAuto;
            break;
    }
}
```

**4)**
No answer on that.
But this is now obsolete when using the solution from 3)

**Edit)**
No answer on that.
But it is working with any way.